# MS Access - adding values

Tags: ms-access

I have a simple table from two fields, words, frequency...

```
- Words            Frequncy
 - ABC             5 
 - DEF             7
 - GHI             9
 - ABC             3
 - DEF             2
 - GHI             1
```

The words are repeated with different frequencies and I want to sum the Frequncy values for each word to

```
 - ABC             8
 - DEF             9
 - GHI            10
```

in a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a GROUP BY clause

```
SELECT Words, SUM(frequency) AS TotalFrequency
FROM the_table
GROUP BY Words
ORDER BY Words;
```

The GROUP BY clause must list all the columns used in the select list to which no aggregate function (like MIN, MAX, AVG or SUM) is applied.

The column name generated for expressions is not defined. In Access, for instance, it depends on the language version of Access. The name might be `SumOfFrequency` in English but `SummeVonFrequency` in German. An application working on one PC might fail on another one. Therefore I suggest defining a column name explicitly with `expr AS column_name`.

Comment: Thank you guys, It worked...is there is a way to discard records with only single character in the words field, the cell have just A, or just b tried * and got everything, tried ? and got nothing

Answer (score 1):

You need a `group by` clause. What this clause does is to, for lack of a better word, group the result for each distinct value in the column(s) specified in it. Then, aggregate functions (like `sum`) can be applied separately for each group. So, in your use case, you'd want to group the rows per value in `Words` and then sum each group's `Frequency`:

```
SELECT   Words, SUM(Frequency)
FROM     MyTable
GROUP BY Words
```

Comment: @ialarmedalien You're right, of course. Didn't occur to me to explain `group by`. Mea culpa.